# WCF Data Service Operation loses order of subEntities in Silverlight Client

Tags: sorting, silverlight, sql-order-by, wcf-data-services, operation

I have a WCF DataService operation, which exposes `Businesses` and `Customers`.

On the server side, I sort each Business's Customers by LastName, this way:

```
List<Customers> orderedCustomers = business.Customers.OrderBy(c=> c.LastName).ToList<Customers>()
business.Customers.Clear()
foreach (Customers customer in orderedCustomers )
business.Customers.Add(customer )
```

And on the client side (asynchronously, in Silverlight), I expand each business's customers like this:

```
Context.BeginExecute<Business>(new Uri(serviceurl + BeginGetAllBusinessData&$expand=Cutomers, UriKind.Relative), GettingBusinessDataCompleted, Context);
```

My issue is: The customers in businesses are not sorted on the client side (they are sorted server-side). It happens the same with any field I choose for the OrderBy. Looks like serialization chooses its own order. I'd like to sort them on the server side.

Am I missing something???

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the returned List is out of order?  If your `GettingBusinessDataCompleted` callback is responsible for adding the expanded content to the UI then things can appear out of sequence.

Asynchronous operations are not guaranteed to complete in the order they were begun.

Comment: Yes, I´m sure. In fact, I´m not painting results yet, just watching them with the VS2010 Quick Watch.

Comment: @Gus:  So I'm unclear now as to whether you really have a problem or not.  If we ignore the second expansion phase for a moment and just concentrate on the initial request to get the list.  Is the list received in order or not?

Comment: In the initial request , when I debug it in server side, the customers list is sorted by any OrderBy I use, but in client it loses the order.